# ViewPager Source Code

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to edit the ViewPager Source code. However, if I add the file to my project it says on the line `mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mObserver);` that the method registerDataSetObserver is invisible. mAdapter here is a [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html). If you look at the developer page, PagerAdapter really has no registerDataSetObserver method. But I also checked the PagerAdapter source code in the SDK. It turns out that there is a registerDataSetObserver method in the source.

I'm a bit confused here. Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

viewpager is available in the compatability package (aka support library) .

why not use the one inside there ?

this way , you can also support older android versions (down to API 4  ).

example : the FragmentTabsPager.java file has it being used , inside the path "...\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos\src\com\example\android\supportv4\app"

Comment: I'm editting the one inside "...\sdk\extras\android\support\v4\src\java\android\support\v4\view". And I'm only going to cater for API 11 and above.

Comment: ok ,so this should be perfect for you. just grab the code that you need from there and that's it . do know that a lot of devices still have API 10 and below , according to android dashboard : http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Well, that's my problem. I try to use the file and I get that invisible method notice like I said above. Can you try it and see what you get?

Comment: so make it public and use it . it's in the same folder you've mentioned . it's open source . what more could you possibly ask for? :)

Comment: i have read it . you need to check the code and change it however you wish to . you don't have to stick with the API in this case . just use the library and change it .